# Efficient way how to check differences between two collections in Java

Tags: java, collections, lambda

I am having a `List` of strings `{1,2,7}`

Now I have a new `List`: `{2,4,9}`

Rules are simple:

1. if element on List A doesn't exist on List B we add it to new delete-list
2. if element on List B doesn't exist on List A we add it to new create-list
3. if element exists on both lists we don't touch it

so the outcome is two new lists:

delete list: `{1,7}`

create list: `{4,9}`

Any idea how to make it efficient within java? perhaps using Java8 to make it easier?

My lists have about 1000 elements.

Comment: Elements are stored in ArrayList or Array?

Comment: You can choose.. doesnt matter as long as it get the purpose .

Comment: if ordering is not important, use `Set` operations such as `addAll()`, `deleteAll()` and `retainAll()`

Comment: Agree with Sasha. Using set will make more sense.

Comment: I edited the question. could you please provide answer?

Comment: this question is WAY too broad and should be closed. Flagged appropriately. Stackoverflow is not your personal homework-portal. Sorry.

Comment: It seems we are just removing the common elements. That is all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ordering is not important, use `Set` bulk operations:

```
Set<String> a = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "7"));
Set<String> b = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("2", "4", "9"));

Set<String> deleteSet = new HashSet<>(a);
deleteSet.removeAll(b);                   // [1, 7]
Set<String> createSet = new HashSet<>(b);
createSet.removeAll(a);                   // [4, 9]
```

If you want Java 8, just filter elements and collect:

```
List<String> deleteList = a.stream().filter(e -> !b.contains(e)).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> createList = b.stream().filter(e -> !a.contains(e)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here, `a` and `b` could be lists, but it is highly recommended to make them `Set`s since `contains()` operation is O(n) in most list implementations.

Comment: There isnt such method deleteAll you meant removeAll?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou: You are missing imports it seems.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou what if my collection element is not string but an object which contain a primitive which I would like to do the compare with

Comment: @rayman if you're using custom class, override its `hashCode()` and `equals()` to follow contract http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29

Comment: gotcha. what about make it more efficient and your parallel stream? do you think it's possible  without side effects?

Comment: @rayman for your counts (~1000) using parallel stream is not worth it, unless `hashCode()` and `equals()` are remarkably expensive.

Comment: But I am going to have this request * 1000 times in a sec.. afraid from performances.

Comment: @rayman then I'd better parallelize calls, not stream processing... anyway, without tests no one would say definitely what is better.

Answer (score 2):

```
delete_list = A.copy();
create_list = B.copy();
delete_list.stream().removeIf(e -> B.contains(e));
create_list.stream().removeIf(e -> A.contains(e));
```

Basically we just create two distinct list. In set theory we can write the output like this:

> delete_list = A \ B
>     create_list = B \ A

Thanks @SashaSalauyou for calling my attention on a mistake i made.

Comment: Sorry, I missed some important requirement and I edited my question please look again

Comment: At line 4 nothing will happen, because at line 3 you remove all common elements from set A.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou oh yeah. Thanks, should've noticed that. I'll edit

Answer (score 1):

Though not very elegant solution but we can also use `Streams` in Java8:

```
Set<String> setOne = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("1","2","7"));
Set<String> setTwo = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("2","4","9"));
System.out.println(setOne.stream().filter(i-> !setTwo.contains(i)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
System.out.println(setTwo.stream().filter(i-> !setOne.contains(i)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

It prints:

`[1, 7]
[4, 9]`

**One important point is that `setOne` and `setTwo` should be effectively final to work in a lambda expression.**